# How to assign a lambda expression to function type variable?

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I'm trying to assign a lambda expression to the following variable:

```
val aba : ((Int) -> Double) -> ((Int) -> Double)
```

the way I am trying to:

```
aba = {(b: (Int -> (Double))-> {x: Int  -> 5 - 2 * b(x)} }
```

but i'm getting different errors like:

1. Expecting comma or ')' (from compiler)
2. Destructing declaration initializer of type (int) -> Double must have a component1() function
   (from editor)

I know that if i will omit *(Int -> (Double)* and leave only b it works:

```
aba = {b  -> {x: Int  -> 5 - 2 * b(x)} }
```

But why can't I explicitly write the parameters?
Some can tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

```
aba = { (b: (Int -> (Double)) -> { x: Int  -> 5 - 2 * b(x) } }
```

is incorrect, because you are missing a closing parenthesis (error 1). After fixing that:

```
aba = { (b: Int -> (Double)) -> { x: Int  -> 5 - 2 * b(x) } }
```

you run into error 2.

The paratheses around the declaration of `b` are in this case incorrect syntax.

You tell the compiler that you want to [destructure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) the parameter of the lambda. But the type does not support that because it does not have a `component1()` function.

```
aba = { b: Int -> (Double) -> { x: Int  -> 5 - 2 * b(x) } }
```

should work.

Note: The reason why you can omit the type declaration of `b` is that the compiler can infer the type, since it knows the type of `aba` from the declaration.

Comment: the line of code you wrote isn't working not because of destrcute issue:
aba = { b: Int -> (Double) -> { x: Int  -> 5 - 2 * b(x) } } 
The editor says on the line above: "unexpected token (use ';' to separate expression on the same line".
And in addition why aba = { b: (Int) -> (Double) -> { x: Int  -> 5 - 2 * b(x) } } won't work

Comment: @Eitanos30 the line you are quoting is the working one. Regarding the first line in my answer: I copied it from you. No matter what the error message says, the parantheses count is off. It would be a good idea to list the snippets along with their respective error messages next time to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

This compiles for me

```kotlin
val aba: ((Int) -> Double) -> ((Int) -> Double) = 
        { b: (Int) -> Double ->
            {x: Int  -> 5 - 2 * b(x)}
        }
```

you don't need the extra brackets when specifying the type of `b`